# firebase-functions.js internal error on calling firebase.functions()

Tags: javascript, firebase

As the title says I am getting an internal error in the firebase-functions.js library when I make any call to firebase.functions().

Some context, this is pure js, not nodeJS, React, or Jquery, and I am attempting a call to an httpsCallable cloud function.  The cloud function is callable and works as expected from android.   The firebase-functions.js library version is 4.13.0.

the error is:

```
Error
​
    code: "internal"
​
    columnNumber: 2043
​
    details: undefined
​
    fileName: "http://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.13.0/firebase-functions.js"
​
    lineNumber: 1
​
    message: "internal"
​
    stack: "t@http://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.13.0/firebase-functions.js:1:2043\nl</e.prototype.call/</</l<@http://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.13.0/firebase-functions.js:1:6501\nl</e.prototype.call/</<@http://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.13.0/firebase-functions.js:1:5803\ns/</<@http://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.13.0/firebase-functions.js:1:1406\ns/<@http://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.13.0/firebase-functions.js:1:755\na@http://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.13.0/firebase-functions.js:1:313\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too using @angular/fire (AngularFire2) which uses firebase inside. If you take a look at the console logs you might be getting CORS ISSUES.

I know there are better ways of doing this but adding the following cors lines to my responses on cloud functions fixed the issue:

```
res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", ["GET", "POST", "OPTIONS"]);
res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", [
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin",
    "Accept",
    "X-Requested-With",
    "Content-Type",
    "Access-Control-Request-Method",
    "Access-Control-Request-Headers",
    'Authorization'
]);
```

This doesn't happen on Android because the device doesn't enforce CORS policy as opposed to web browser platforms.

Comment: How do you get access to `res` in an `onCall` function?